# OpenID authentication goes into strange error loop (Ruby on Rails, ruby-openid, open_id_authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, ruby-openid

I've been using OpenID for my site for a while, and everything has been working fine.  However, recently I've been seeing some strange errors in the error logs.  Apparently, everything works fine for the user, and they're able to log in.  However, in the background, the OpenID library seems to go into a loop that causes a bunch of errors.

Also, It only happens when I'm not accessing on localhost:3000  If I tunnel requests through my DynDns name, I get the error.  If I come from localhost:3000, nothing

At the bottom is a snippet from the logs.  The main thing to note is the first few lines:

```
No pre-discovered information supplied
Performing discovery on http://XXX.myopenid.com/
```

This comes in a few seconds after the initial OpenID request, and immediately results in the following error and stacktrace.  This continues for a couple times, then stops.

Anyone know what's going one?

```
No pre-discovered information supplied
Performing discovery on http://XXX.myopenid.com/

Processing SessionsController#create (for 66.249.70.239 at 2009-01-11 09:20:38) [GET]
  Session ID: 19b48e16d003d796e4b90674b3a2b917
  Parameters: {"openid.sreg.nickname"=>"ASDF", "openid.claimed_id"=>"http://XXX.myopenid.com/", "openid.mode"=>"id_res", "openid.ns.sreg"=>"http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1", "openid.return_to"=>"http://XXX.homelinux.net:3000/sessions?open_id_complete=1", "openid.sig"=>"Xs3twfOutebf5edn5eXaM0OTMko=", "openid.sreg.fullname"=>"ASDF", "openid.ns"=>"http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0", "openid.op_endpoint"=>"http://www.myopenid.com/server", "action"=>"create", "openid.response_nonce"=>"2009-01-11T14:20:31Z20d5QU", "method"=>:get, "controller"=>"sessions", "openid.sreg.email"=>"ASDF@FDSA.com", "openid.identity"=>"http://XXX.myopenid.com/", "openid.sreg.country"=>"US", "open_id_complete"=>"1", "openid.assoc_handle"=>"{HMAC-SHA1}{4968a37c}{NUOe7g==}", "openid.signed"=>"assoc_handle,claimed_id,identity,mode,ns,ns.sreg,op_endpoint,response_nonce,return_to,signed,sreg.country,sreg.email,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname"}
  OpenIdAuthentication::Association Load (0.002034)   SELECT * FROM `open_id_authentication_associations` WHERE (`open_id_authentication_associations`.`server_url` = 'http://www.myopenid.com/server' AND `open_id_authentication_associations`.`handle` = '{HMAC-SHA1}{4968a37c}{NUOe7g==}') 
  OpenIdAuthentication::Nonce Load (0.000717)   SELECT * FROM `open_id_authentication_nonces` WHERE (`open_id_authentication_nonces`.`server_url` = 'http://www.myopenid.com/server' AND `open_id_authentication_nonces`.`timestamp` = 1231683631 AND `open_id_authentication_nonces`.`salt` = '20d5QU') LIMIT 1


NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.claimed_id):
    /vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:107:in `complete_open_id_authentication'
    /vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:88:in `authenticate_with_open_id'
    /app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:80:in `open_id_authentication'
    /app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1158:in `send'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1158:in `perform_action_without_filters'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:697:in `call_filters'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:689:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:199:in `perform_action_without_caching'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:678:in `perform_action'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:33:in `cache'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:677:in `perform_action'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `send'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in `process_without_filters'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:685:in `process_without_session_management_support'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:123:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:388:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:171:in `handle_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:115:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:126:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:9:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    script/server:3

No pre-discovered information supplied
Performing discovery on http://myid.myopenid.com/
```

Comment: have you tried to update the plugin to latest version?

just trying to guess .. what isn't suppose to be nil? probably it can't load the user?

Comment: Yeah I agree with Sikachu, that is definitely not the latest version of the plugin as 107 does not call the method listing. Give upgrading it a shot!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give upgrading a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest ruby-openid, open_id_authentication, and Rails 2.2.2 fixed it!

Thanks for the suggestions.